# Pyspark dataframe withcolumn or line max limit

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have a pyspark notebook created in databricks.  I have a dataframe, to which i need to add columns dynamically, and currently the number of columns are 186.  When I reach python line to a length of 10000, i dont see the color codings for None, Lit, etc. and my notebook cell fails to recognize the withcolumn declarations after the line size reaches 10000.

Is there any size limit for a line in python? If so, is there any better way to add these many columns to a dataframe, using a list?

Thanks,

Yuva

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There is a limit for selecting a no. of columns from a dataframe in databricks, You can select your all columns by using a list. Like this -

```
df = prv_df.withColumn(******something*********)

cols = ['column_1'
       ,'column_2'
       ,
       ,
       ,
       ,'column_n']

new_df = df.select(cols)
```

I think it solve your issue.